# Have Swagger to substitute servicestack meta

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I was wondering if it's possible to have swagger to serve pages at place of SS metadata page... I'm asking this since SS metadata is quite usefull when you've a lot of services

as far I've seen I can remove the feature on SS configuration, disable the httphandler but don't know how to go further

Thanks

Comment: Would a redirect from `/metadata` to to swagger be sufficient? Or are you trying to add a link in the Swagger UI to the /metadata? I am unclear which way you want to go.

Comment: I wanto to completly remove the metadata of servicestack and have the swagger one when I point to address/api/metadata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So remove the `MetaDataFeature` in the AppHost Configure method:

```cs
SetConfig(new HostConfig { 
    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Metadata)
});
```

Then create this simple MetaData service, that redirects to Swagger.

```cs
[Route("/metadata/{cmds*}", "GET")]
public class RedirectToSwaggerRequest : IReturnVoid 
{
    public string cmds { get; set; }
}

[Restrict(VisibleLocalhostOnly = true)]
public class MetadataService : Service
{
    public void Get(RedirectToSwaggerRequest request)
    {
        base.Response.Redirect("/swagger-ui");
    }
}
```

*Note: `{cmds*}` in the route above will catch requests for `/metadata`, `/metadata/something` & `/metadata/somethingelse` etc.*

Then when a request goes to `/metadata` then it will redirect to Swagger instead.

Comment: Hello scott, I've done what you told but I got this exception Could not find property cmds on RedirectToSwaggerRequest

Comment: @advapi I have updated the code to include this property now. You need to add `public string cmds { get; set; }` to the `RedirectToSwaggerRequest`.

Comment: Ok it works...just a last question...it's possible to hide the swagger redirect service from the shown serivices?

Comment: @advapi You can hide the service to everybody except `localhost` by using this `[Restrict(VisibleLocalhostOnly = true)]` attribute on the service. Have updated.